# Docker Openedx devstack theming

Tags: docker, devstack, openedx

How do I install and enable my custom theme in OpenEdx's  docker based DevStack?

- I use comprehensive theming
- I use docker on Linux

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) a good question and update yours accordingly. As it is currently written, it may be closed as a "too broad" question.

Comment: Welcome! Please be more specific and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The LMS and CMS read many configuration settings from the container filesystem in the following locations:

> /edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json
>
> /edx/app/edxapp/cms.auth.json

Since you are using docker DevStack, shell into LMS, CMS to find those files.

shell into LMS

```
make lms-shell
```

Shell into CMS

```
make studio-shell
```

You can create this directory at any location on a file system that is accessible to your Open edX installation. For example, you might place it at the root of the file system in a directory named **/my-open-edx-themes**.

Set the file permissions on the themes directory, and all of its subdirectories, to enable read+write permissions for the Ubuntu user.

```
sudo chown -R edxapp:edxapp /my-open-edx-themes
sudo chmod -R u+rw /my-open-edx-themes
```

For each Open edX component that you want to theme, set the

> "ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING" = True
>
> "DEFAULT_SITE_THEME": "Your-theme-name "

For LMS,

> /edx/app/edxapp/lms.env.json

For Studio,

> /edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json

For the E-commerce,

> /edx/etc/ecommerce.yml

And for each Open edX component that you want to apply a theme to, add the absolute path of the themes directory to the

> COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS

configuration property.

For LMS and Studio,

```
"COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS": [
    "/my-open-edx-themes/edx-platform"
]
```

For the E-commerce,

```
COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS: ["/my-open-edx-themes/ecommerce"]
```

Finally, Restart all servers.

For more info, please follow this documentation.

http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/changing_appearance/theming/enable_themes.html

Add comments if you have any additional questions.

Comment: I believe the question is how to persist the settings in docker since the theme configuration is not persisted once docker is restarted.