# How to fix the error in the raccoon themes in Open edX

Tags: openedx

I am setting up a new Open edX and install the raccoon theme https://themex.io/theme/marvel-yellow/ It is installed successfully.

But Theme changes not affected in the header.

Comment: I think you better to explain how you enable the theme and after enabled have you restart the lms?

Comment: For installation, I am following this blog   https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/open-edx-custom-theming-tutorial/ and I found the theme on GitHub https://github.com/sbernesto/marvel.

Comment: If you have followed Lawrence's blog, then it should work. It has clearly described everything. Please double check everything. Here you can see one of my previous answers as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356691/docker-openedx-devstack-theming

Comment: I have already restarted the LMS - sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart lms but not working. I have installed  open-release/hawthorn.2 release and theme need to Dogwood fullstack version https://themex.io/install/

Comment: Yes, the theme needs to be compatible, But if you have some idea, you can make that happen.